# Cant upgrade php version on MacOS Catalina

Tags: php, laravel

I have a very annoying problem. I have 2 versions of PHP on MacOS Catalina, and no matter what I do, I cant seem to get rid of the old (php 7.3.x) version. I can't change anything in /usr/bin/ on my Mac, even though I'm an admin user.

The 2 versions of PHP are:

```
$ /usr/bin/php -v
PHP 7.3.11 (cli) (built: Apr 17 2020 19:14:14) ( NTS )
```

```
$ /usr/local/bin/php -v
PHP 7.4.9 (cli) (built: Aug  7 2020 19:23:06) ( NTS )
```

Even though `which php` and `php -v` use 7.4:

```
$ which php
/usr/local/bin/php
```

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.4.9 (cli) (built: Aug  7 2020 19:23:06) ( NTS )
```

The problem is that when my cron job runs, it uses /usr/bin/php (version 7.3.x), making my cron job fail (turns out some Laravel package code - specifically [Mailcoach](https://mailcoach.app) - is not compiant with php 7.3.* and NEEDS php v 7.4 or above.

This is what my PATH variable looks like:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin/php:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:./vendor/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/kunalpunjabi/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin/mysql
```

If you've encountered this before or know how to fix it, please help!

Comment: Could you please check your settings for the `schedule:run` cronjob and see if it's set to use `/usr/local/bin/php` instead of `/usr/bin/php`?

Personally, I'd always use a Virtual Machine like Docker so I have complete control over my dev env. If anything on my OS changes, I won't have troubles with dependencies, versions etc.

Comment: @GlennM with ```* * * * * cd /scheduler_crons && /usr/local/bin/php artisan schedule:run``` it works fine, but I need to upgrade /usr/bin/php. thats what this question is about.....I need this crontab to also work: ```* * * * * cd /scheduler_crons && php artisan schedule:run```, which it doesnt because of incorrect php version

Answer (score 0):

Did you install them trough homebrew?

If so try linking php7.4

First look at what php is currently running trough

```
brew services list
```

Then stop and unlink that version with

```
brew services stop {PHP}
brew unlink {PHP}
```

Then link the correct version

```
brew link --force --overwrite php@7.4
brew services start php@7.4
```

Could you try this?

If this not works, could you upload a screenshot of your 'brew services list'

Comment: I just tried those steps and it didnt help. The problem is not of the main php version installed with brew, which has always shown 7.4.9. The problem is the version used by the cron is /usr/bin/php which is v 7.3 - that is the version i need to get rid of. Also see:

```$ brew services list
Name    Status  User         Plist           
mysql   started kp123 /Users/kp123/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
php     started kp123 /Users/kp123/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.php.plist```